# Android Kotlin Real-Time FFT and plot

Tags: android, kotlin, fft, android-graphview

I am trying to apply Real-time FFT on a sensor data which is connected over the bluetooth BLE.

There is a sdk which allows you to receive the data from the sensor in the Android using handler. I am using ViewModel to send the sensor data in various parts of the app to plot the data using [GraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView) and perform FFT.

I am using [JTransform](https://github.com/wendykierp/JTransforms) to perform the FFT but before I was using [JDSP](https://github.com/psambit9791/jDSP/wiki/Short-Time-Fourier-Transforms) to perform STFT.

Below is the code use to perform FFT on a unfiltered raw sensor data using JTransform

```
    var t = 0
    var fs  = 512
    var sampleSize = 2*fs
    val windowSize = sampleSize/2
    
    private fun getFFT(sample:DoubleArray): Array<DataPoint>{
        val fft = DoubleFFT_1D(sampleSize.toLong())
        fft.realForward(sample)
        return analysed(sample)
    } 
    
    private fun analysed(sample:DoubleArray): Array<DataPoint> {
        val series:Array<DataPoint> =  Array(sample.size) { i -> DataPoint(0.0,0.0) }
        sample.forEachIndexed { i, y -> 
            val x = i.toDouble()
            series[i] = DataPoint(x, y)
        }
        return series
    }

    
    sensorViewModel.getRaw().observe(this){
        if(t<sampleSize-1){
            sample[t] = it.toDouble()
            t++
        }else{
            sample = sample.takeLast(windowSize).toDoubleArray().plus(DoubleArray(2*windowSize) { i -> 0.0 })
            t = windowSize

            // Plot FFT
            asyncTask.execute(onPreExecute = {
            }, doInBackground = {
                getFFT(sample)
            }, onPostExecute = {
                fftseries.resetData(it)
            })
        }
    }
```

Although my code runs without crash but I can see so many problems with the app.

1. Using a sliding window to create "sample" to perform FFT on the created sample feels really inefficient. Can anyone please suggest how can I do write it better with the better control of window size.
2. How to make this FFT plot fast?

Comment: Noticed that you create a new `DoubleFFT_1D` every iteration. You should probably use the [CPU Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler) to see where time is spent.

Comment: oh that was an oversight. I took it out but no performance changes.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I forgot to post the solution which I figured out long back. The problem was not with this code. It was viewmodel class. I was updating the values with postValues() so I changed it to setValues() and it is working fine.